# Where is Qt designer app on Mac + Anaconda?

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt, anaconda

I am trying to find Qt designer app on Mac. I installed anaconda package and conda reports that qt, sip, and pyqt are installed. Still I couldn't find the designer app in any of the folders. My Python app that uses pyqt works perfectly. I'm very new to macs and probably missing something very simple.

I did search folder tree for anything named designer. I found QtDesigner.so (supposed to be executable?) at
/Users/XXXX/anaconda/pkgs/pyqt-4.10.4-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4 but it won't even run saying "cannot execute binary file"
anaconda/bin doesn't have it.

There's a folder anaconda/include/QtDesigner but noting I can run
/anaconda/pkgs/qt-4.8.5-3/bin - no designer. I'm totally confused now.

Comment: What makes you think it's even installed? BTW, a quick google would have shown you that a `.so` file is a library.

Comment: Hmm... I previously used another scientific python package pythonxy and it was installed along with qt and pyqt so I assumed it was part of the qt installation.
But you are right. It's a part of Qt Creator package.

Comment: In Windows 10,,, mine was located under %UserProfile%\Anaconda3\Library\bin\designer.exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I expect it's Qt Creator that you should be looking for. [Note here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator): -

> *the integration of Qt Designer under Qt Creator is first mentioned at least as early as Qt 4.7 (ca. late 2011)*
>
> *Qt Creator includes a code editor and integrates Qt Designer for designing and building graphical user interfaces (GUIs) from Qt widgets.*

If it's not in your distribution, you can download it separately [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator).

Comment: Thanks Merlin069. I installed Qt Creator from the link but when I try to open .ui file created by Qt Designer it gives me The application "Qt.Designer" could not be found.

Comment: If you create a new project, such as a "Qt Widgets Application", does it give you a Form with a ui that you can open and edit?

Comment: I found it! :) There was an option to Open File or Project that opens ui files in Designer without problems. If I select Open File With - Qt Designer it gives an error.

Answer (score 17):

You can try `open -a Designer` from your terminal to launch Qt Designer that comes with Anaconda (version 4.x).

If you have Qt5.x, you may want to launch a newer version of Designer by `open -a Designer-qt5`.

Comment: I installed with Anaconda (conda install pyqt) but "open -a Designer-qt5" gives the error "Unable to find application named 'Designer-qt5'"

Comment: Thank you. The command line open -a Designer helps

Answer (score 6):

`OSX Yosemite 10.10.5`
`Qt 5.6`
`QtCreator 3.6.1`

QtDesigner is part of my QtCreator.  To use QtDesigner:

1. Launch QtCreator, and from the menu bar (outside QtCreator), click on:
   `File>New File or Project`
2. You will be presented with a `New File or Project` dialog window.  In the `Files And Classes` section, select `Qt`.  In the middle pane, select `QtDesigner Form`.  Then click on the `Choose` button in the lower right corner.
3. You will be presented with a `QtDesigner Form` dialog window.  Then you can select `Main Window` or `Dialog with Buttons Bottom`, etc. Then click on the `Continue` button in the lower right corner.
4. In the `Location` dialog window, use a name like mainwindow1.ui, and for the path you might want to step aside and create a directory called forms, e.g. `$ mkdir /Users/7stud/qt_projects/forms`, then enter that as the path.
5. Enter any other details and click on `Done`.   That will land you in QtCreator with the Design button selected (which I guess means you are in QtDesigner), and you will be able to drag and drop widgets onto your window.
6. To convert the `.ui` file to a `.py` file that you can import into your python program:

   `$ pyuic5 mainwindow1.ui -o mainwindow1.py`

   `-o => output file (default is stdout)`

That command converts the .ui file mainwindow1.ui to a .py file named mainwindow1.py.

To re-open the file: `File>Open File or Project`.  If you select a file with a .ui extension, it will be opened with QtCreator's Design button pre-selected, i.e. you will be inside QtDesigner.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the latest Qt4 version for Mac (and SIP), from https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download/
python configure.py
make && make install
and my qt designer is here.
/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/Designer.app

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I found it in this location in my mac

/Users/ramakrishna/Qt/5.11.1/clang_64/bin/Designer.app

command "open -a designer" also works on mac shell

command + space bar and invoke spot light search and typing designer also find the designer app

Answer (score 1):

Qt has a dmg installer for Mac which includes everything.

https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer

Answer (score 1):

There is a much lighter version of QT Creator with just Python QT Editor which helps You to build Python UI sweet and simple . Even no conversion for ui files required (it allow You to do it in realtime...)
i really love it !!!!
https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer you question definitively as I don't have OSX installed anywhere, but perhaps I can help lead you in the right direction.

1) you are going to want to be looking for Designer, not QT Creator, as Designer is what comes bundled with PyQt4 (PyQt4 is what Anaconda comes packaged with)

2) in linux when you install Anaconda 2.1 to the default location, designer is going to be placed in home/user_name/anaconda/bin/

3) typing 'designer' from a terminal launches designer in linux, so you may not have to bother searching around for it.

Hopefully there is some consistency between linux and osx (windows designer is located in \Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4).

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
open -a Designer
```

from mac terminal works on macOS Big Sur 11.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Try here:
/opt/homebrew/opt/qt@5/bin/Designer