# Is Qt Designer bundled with Anaconda?

Tags: python, qt, anaconda

I am using Python 3.4 via anaconda 4.0 which has all of the pyQt4 modules packaged with it. Can I use the Qt Designer with this?
When I look in /anaconda/pkgs/qt-4.8.7-1/bin there is a Qt icon called Designer, but clicking it yields nothing more than "Designer cannot be opened because of a problem".

Before you all shout at me, the similar question posted at
[Where is Qt designer app on mac + Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226730/where-is-qt-designer-app-on-mac-anaconda)
didn't help me. I tried downloading QtCreator and it doesn't seem to find any other python packages I have installed (not that I actually know what I'm doing).

If I install Qt in its entirety to get the Designer will it cause any confusion with the Qt packages I have installed under Anaconda?

Answer (score 31):

In `anaconda\Library\bin` there exists a `designer.exe` for me.

Anaconda version 4.0.0

Comment: On a Mac, you will need to use Designer.app, which is located at (if the anaconda3 is installed in the default directory): ~/anaconda3/bin/Designer.app. Just open that, or drag that to /Applications/

Comment: Windows 10: Mine was located under  %UserProfile%\Anaconda3\Library\bin\designer.exe

Answer (score 22):

I was also looking for a QT designer on my Windows 7 which was installed Anaconda 5.1.
The easy way to run a QT designer is that:
Run "*Anaconda Prompt*" then type `designer` in the command shell. You will have a QT designer.

Comment: I just ran "designer" straight from windows 10 command line! I was looking everywhere for it!!!

Answer (score 10):

To start QtDesigner in Anaconda:

1. Activate conda environment (if it is not already active) in the terminal:

   $ conda activate
2. Type "designer" at the prompt (in the activated terminal, of course):

   (base) $ designer

For advanced users:

If you want a bash file with a desktop launcher, here is the code for each:

First make a folder "bin" at /home/user_name/bin and put your designer.sh file there.

The desktop launcher file can be placed anywhere (on the desktop should be fine).

designer.sh code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo ""
. /home/user_name/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
designer
```

designer.desktop code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Anaconda-Designer
GenericName=AnacondaDesign
Exec=/bin/bash "/home/user_name/bin/designer.sh"
Icon=/home/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/static/images/qtcreator-icon-1024x1024.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

Don't forget to give executable permissions for these two files and to accept as "trusted" the desktop launcher application (on first launch).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I have installed *Anaconda 3* and I have found the Designer in 
`/Users/apple/anaconda/bin/Designer.app/Contents/MacOS`.
It works fine

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer for myself...

It was simply a case of deleting the Anaconda directory and reinstalling it. All seems to work fine now

Answer (score 2):

I am using conda 4.9.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. QtDesigner comes with conda package. For my case, I need to run first `conda activate <env name>` then `qt5-tools designer` to open QtDesigner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Anaconda packages does have QtDesigner package.

You can check the location of Designer using following steps -
first go to the python version installed in your machine, for mac you can type - 
which python3
Go this location, and then look for QtDesigner.

There you are.

Thank You