# anaconda python: create qtdesigner shortcut?

Tags: python, anaconda, shortcut

I'm an Anaconda / Python user and I would like to add a qtdesigner launcher in the anaconda-navigator (and later, my own applications). Any Idea on how to do that?

I assume it is simple because it's a "shortcut manager" but I find nothing clear, certainly beause I don't have the keywords.

thx for help

Comment: Mac, Windows or Linux? for mac: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226730/where-is-qt-designer-app-on-mac-anaconda

Answer (score 0):

maybe a beginning of answer here:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/

https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/index.html

My issue is not about where is the designer, but how to create a shortcut in anaconda navigator.